# Avoid paragraph due to trailing empty line in standalone file

Tags: paragraphs, standalone

Using my `standalone` class and package it is possible to compile diagrams etc. inside own files stand-alone or as part of a main document. However, a common user error is to keep an empty line between the end of the content and the `\end{document}` which causes the diagram etc. to be part of a paragraph and the resulting PDF will be `\linewidth` wide. I'm looking now for possibilities to ignore such trailing lines or remove the paragraph they create.

The following MWE shows the issue and also includes a potential redefinition of the internal `\sa@cls@beforeenddocument` macro which is placed at the beginning of `\end{document}`. Maybe this issue can be solves with some `\lastbox` trickery.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\def\sa@cls@beforeenddocument{%
    \ifhmode
        \unskip
    \else
        % ???
    \fi
    \endstandalone 
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Current Restult]

The wanted result is:

[image: Wanted Result]

(Shown is the full "page". The dark border is the background color of Adobe Reader.)

Comment: You can't undo what has already been put on the main vertical list. The only way I see is to redefine `\par` to look forward for `\end{document}` and to take appropriate action if it's found with "nothing" intervening.

Comment: @egreg: :-( I wanted to avoid such things.

Comment: When a paragraph has been formed there's very little that can be done. Except acting through the output routine, but this would open a can of worms. Setting ``\catcode`\^^M=10`` would ignore empty lines in the input (they would be seen as spaces). This would force to use `\par` explicitly in such files when a real paragraph is desired.

Comment: @egreg: And when I store the whole content in a saved vbox? Can I then do something more? The whole content should be placed on one page anyway.

Comment: The problem would be exactly the same: `\vbox{\leavevmode...}` builds a paragraph with the current `\hsize`.

Comment: Probably not what you'd want, and I'm even not sure whether I'm correct (that's whay I'm posting a comment and not an answer;)), but I guess that you could do it in lua(La)TeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a paragraph has been formed there's very little that can be done, except acting through the output routine, but this would open a can of worms.

Setting `` \catcode`\^^M=10 `` would ignore empty lines in the input (they would be seen as spaces). This would force to use `\par` explicitly in such files when a real paragraph is desired.

One can also think to redefine `\par` to look forward in order to see if `\end{document}` intervenes with "nothing" (except blank spaces or empty lines) intervening, but this can lead to other problems for normal text.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Not the answer I was hoping for, though. Maybe I implement my own `preview` like code which enforces a `\hbox` instead of `\vbox` and let users of the `standalone` class choice which one to use.

Comment: I think the `varwidth` environment/package might be useful here. It seems to handle this case well.

Comment: Tanks again @egreg. I overcame this issue in the new v1.0 of `standalone` by using either the `varwidth` environment from the package of the same name, now also the option name, and/or by boxing the content myself as part of the new `crop` option.