# standalone figure and tabular

Tags: standalone

I'd like to generate a standalone pdf containing a pgf/tikz image and a tabular.

I'm almost getting the desired result but there is a paragraph between the image and the tabular that breaks my layout (I guess it is due to the fact that the empty paragraph takes the full textwidth).

What I do to get such result is the following:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
...
\end{tikzpicture}
 %This empty line creates the undesired paragraph
\begin{tabular}
...
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could just crop the resulting standalone pdf...

Comment: Yes, the paragraph causes the full text width. I tried to build something into `standalone` to avoid this and asked the following question for that: [Avoid paragraph due to trailing empty line in standalone file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23279/avoid-paragraph-due-to-trailing-empty-line-in-standalone-file). Unfortunately, this can't be fixed by `standalone` itself.

Comment: @Seamus I'd like to avoid that. It was the reason I decided to use the standalone package

Comment: @MartinScharrer I'll have a look at the linked discussion. Thanks

Comment: @mariosangiorgio: Please note my updated answer. The new version of `standalone` makes things much easier.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Update 2011/12/21

I now release `standalone` v1.0 which comes with a `varwidth` option to allow
for vertical content with variable width. It uses the `varwidth` environment (and package) internally which is based on `minipage`. Using this option
you can use a paragraph break (i.e. an empty line) to stack both things. If you
want more vertical space try a `\vspace{..}` between them.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}[2011/12/21]
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (2,3);
\end{tikzpicture}%

\begin{tabular}{cc}
 a & b \\\hline
 b & c \\
 d & e \\
\end{tabular}%
\end{document}
```

---

#### Original answer:

You need to stack the two elements manually without using a line break or new paragraph. You can use a TikZ picture like Ignasi suggested, wrap both into a `tabular` or use `\shortstack{...\\...}`. It is also possible to stack it using plainTeX commands: `\vbox{\hbox{..}\hbox{..}}`.

Examples:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\vbox{\hbox{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (2,3);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}\hbox{%
\begin{tabular}{cc}
 a & b \\\hline
 b & c \\
 d & e \\
\end{tabular}%
}}%
\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\shortstack{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (2,3);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\\%
\begin{tabular}{cc}
 a & b \\\hline
 b & c \\
 d & e \\
\end{tabular}%
}%
\end{document}
```

With the optional argument of `\shortstack` you can select the horizontal alignment of the blocks.

I reused the example code from Ignasi to allow for easy comparison.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: I didn't know how to automatically adjust output width. Now, I know three ways of doing it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If it's possible you can include your tabular inside the tikzpicture.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (figure) at (0,0) {\tikz \draw (0,0) rectangle (2,3);};
\node (tabular) [below = of figure] {\begin{tabular}{cc}
 a & b \\\hline
 b & c \\
 d & e \\
\end{tabular}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I've tested `standalone` and `preview` but although cropped height is correct, cropped width is textwidth. If you know final width, you can use a `minipage` to fix it.