# Crop in Standalone class

Tags: tkz-collection, crop, standalone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Standalone package creates a page with a fixed width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34590/standalone-package-creates-a-page-with-a-fixed-width)

How do I get the class standalone crop the image just as you would preview the package? I must get over the side that is because the package tkz-euclide.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
  \usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage[pdfpagelayout=SinglePage]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzInit
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
  \tkzDefPoint(4,0){B}
  \tkzDefTriangle[equilateral](A,B)
  \tkzGetPoint{C}
  %angulos
  \tkzMarkAngle[fill=green!50,size=5mm](B,A,C) %\apha
  \tkzMarkAngle[fill=green!50,size=5mm](A,C,B) %\beta
  \tkzMarkAngle[fill=green!50,size=5mm](C,B,A) %\gamma
  %rotulos
  \tkzLabelPoints[below](A,B)
  \tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
  \tkzLabelAngle[pos=.7](B,A,C){$\alpha$}
  \tkzLabelAngle[pos=.7](C,B,A){$\beta$}
  \tkzLabelAngle[pos=.7](A,C,B){$\gamma$}
  \tkzLabelSegment[above right](B,C){$a$}
  \tkzLabelSegment[above left](C,A){$b$}
  \tkzLabelSegment[below](A,B){$c$}
  %triangulo equilatero
  \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
  %pontos
  \tkzDrawPoints[fill=blue](A,B,C)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Does not show here, but the image was not cut from the right side.

Comment: The next version of `standalone` will avoid this problem. But it isn't actual that easy to do automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the blank line at end of the file will fix the problem.
You should also remove the blank line at the beginning, but that does not seem to affect the cropping.

Also see [Standalone package creates a page with a fixed width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34590/standalone-package-creates-a-page-with-a-fixed-width/34596#34596) as sometimes the issue is more than just a blank line.

Comment: Or a `%` on that line if you prefer to keep it for clarity.

Comment: Ours, because it works with ``%`` ? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, could you please rephrase?