# Difference with standalone and preview?

Tags: pdftex, preview, standalone

I have a table, but for cleanliness (I'll use the figure in a paper and in talks), I'd like to compile to a single PDF and include it with `includegraphics` instead of having the table rendered within the paper.

In the paper, it renders fine. I use these options:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
```

But when I move the table into a `standalone` document with preview, the graphics are far too big for the page. **Of course, I can still simply render the figure in its own table inside paper.tex, but I'd like to figure out why this happens. Can you figure it out?**

**Here is the preview document:**

```
\documentclass[preview=true]{standalone}

\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{m{0.1in}m{1.4in}m{1.4in}m{1.4in}m{1.4in}m{1.4in}}
  &
\multirow{3}{*}{\begin{minipage}{1.4in}\centering {\bf (a)} Control-control densities \end{minipage}} &
 % 1.4 * 3
 \multicolumn{3}{c}{ \begin{minipage}{4.2in}\centering {\bf (b)} Case-control vs. control-control log densities \end{minipage} } \\
 & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{ \begin{minipage}{4.2in}\centering {\includegraphics[width=4.2in]{colorbar.pdf}} \end{minipage} }\\

 & & \begin{minipage}{1.4in} \centering {0 differential} \end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}{1.4in} \centering {53 differential} \end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}{1.4in} \centering {302 differential} \end{minipage}\\

 \begin{sideways}Replicate 1\end{sideways} & 
  \includegraphics[width=1.4in]{null_1-crop.pdf} &
  \includegraphics[width=1.4in]{rep_1_0-crop.pdf} &
  \includegraphics[width=1.4in]{rep_1_53-crop.pdf} &
  \includegraphics[width=1.4in]{rep_1_302-crop.pdf} \\

 \begin{sideways}Replicate 2\end{sideways} & 
  \includegraphics[width=1.4in]{null_2-crop.pdf} &
  \includegraphics[width=1.4in]{rep_2_0-crop.pdf} &
  \includegraphics[width=1.4in]{rep_2_53-crop.pdf} &
  \includegraphics[width=1.4in]{rep_2_302-crop.pdf} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: why don't you use `\documentclass[border=15pt]{standalone}`? without the setting of `preview=true`!

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure-- can you enlighten me below? I would be happy to +1 and accept a superior solution.

Comment: try it out ... with your example and without loading the package geometry.

Comment: I agree with Herbert. Just remove the `preview=true` option and control the border margins with the `border` option as Herbert has suggested.

Comment: Also, `\usepackage{standalone}` is superfluous in your MWE.

Comment: With the `preview` option you need to make sure that there are no empty lines between the content and the `\end{document}`. They create a paragraph break which influences the official width. See [Standalone package creates a page with a fixed width](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34590) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Ah-- it was this line:

```
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
```

Adding it to the standalone document did the trick.

Comment: I'm the author of `standalone`. Using `geometry` with the `standalone` class should not be required and is in general not recommended, because then both will influence the page margin or size.

Answer (score 1):

When I remove the trailing empty line after the table or remove the `preview` option (`standalone` v1.x) then the issues disappear. Please see [Standalone package creates a page with a fixed width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34590) which explains why this happens with the `preview` option. Because of this I consider your question a duplicate of that question and will close it as such shortly.
However, I wanted to post the corrected code for you before that. Please find it below.

Note that you also don't need to load the `standalone` *package* as long you don't want to include other `standalone` documents. Please also don't use the old LaTeX 2.0 font macros like `\bf` any longer. See ["Correct" way to bold/italicize text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41681/2975) for an explanation.

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{m{0.1in}m{1.4in}m{1.4in}m{1.4in}m{1.4in}m{1.4in}}
  &
\multirow{3}{*}{\begin{minipage}{1.4in}\centering {\bfseries (a)} Control-control densities \end{minipage}} &
 % 1.4 * 3
 \multicolumn{3}{c}{ \begin{minipage}{4.2in}\centering {\bfseries (b)} Case-control vs. control-control log densities \end{minipage} } \\
 & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{ \begin{minipage}{4.2in}\centering {\includegraphics[width=4.2in]{example-image.pdf}} \end{minipage} }\\

 & & \begin{minipage}{1.4in} \centering {0 differential} \end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}{1.4in} \centering {53 differential} \end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}{1.4in} \centering {302 differential} \end{minipage}\\

 \begin{sideways}Replicate 1\end{sideways} &
  \includegraphics[width=1.4in]{example-image.pdf} &
  \includegraphics[width=1.4in]{example-image.pdf} &
  \includegraphics[width=1.4in]{example-image.pdf} &
  \includegraphics[width=1.4in]{example-image.pdf} \\

 \begin{sideways}Replicate 2\end{sideways} &
  \includegraphics[width=1.4in]{example-image.pdf} &
  \includegraphics[width=1.4in]{example-image.pdf} &
  \includegraphics[width=1.4in]{example-image.pdf} &
  \includegraphics[width=1.4in]{example-image.pdf} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you read my bug report e-mail? [Here](http://pastebin.com/aANZdNV1) is the code to regenerate the issue.

Comment: @ClickMe: Please use the chat or email for such messages and not unrelated posts. I have read it but didn't had time to test it. What makes you think this is a bug in `standalone`? Probably the `gather*` environment adds the space somehow.