# Crop entire document around figure

Tags: tables, pdfcrop

Have you ever submitted a LaTeX paper to a journal that wants *separate* figures? When you want to include a figure composed of a table of images, you must build it separately.

When I run `latexpdf`, I get an entire 8.5 x 11 page, even when I remove the page number.

Is there a way to "autocrop" my built pdf as I compile it from LaTeX? I suppose I could open it in inkscape and crop and save it, but I'd really like to learn how to do this the *right way*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have been using [the `standalone` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/standalone) exactly for this purpose. You create a standalone tex file for each figure and use:

```
\documentclass[preview=true]{standalone}
```

and the main files which `include` this standalone file will need to have the complete preamble including `\usepackage{standalone}`. Martin Scharrer, the package author provides a [good example here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12267/using-subfiles-package-with-sty-files/12268#12268).

---

Alternatively you could use [the `preview` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/preview). Add `\usepackage[active, graphics]{preview}`, and use the `\PreviewEnvironment` to specify which environments you want to be extracted.

Here is an example that extracts the two `tikzpicture` environments on separate pages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{1pt}%

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [red, ultra thick] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [blue,fill=yellow] (0,0) circle (5pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 This sounds exactly like what I want. But I don't seem to have the package, despite having installed `texlive-full`. Do you know how to get the package (I'm using Ubuntu)?

Comment: Which package? Both `preview` and `standalone` are part of the normal distribution. I have added links to the answer as to where the packages are.

Comment: Both are availble from CTAN: [`standalone`](http://ctan.org/pkg/standalone) and [`preview`](http://ctan.org/pkg/preview) and should form part of TeX Live. Install these using [`tlmgr`](http://www.tug.org/texlive/tlmgr.html).

Comment: @Werner: The TeXLive version of Ubuntu is from 2009 and doesn't include `tlmgr`.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: That's old-school... I guess it's a manual installation then.

Comment: @Oliver: If you still have the (utterly outdated) TeXLive version which ships with Ubuntu then consider installing it manually: [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu). Otherwise try a `sudo tlmgr install preview standalone` on the command line.

Comment: You can also install it manually: [How to install LaTeX .zip package (from CTAN) using texhash on a 'nix system?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30307/how-to-install-latex-zip-package-from-ctan-using-texhash-on-a-nix-system)
. The TDS ZIP file for `standalone` is at http://mirror.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/standalone.tds.zip.

Comment: I've installed LaTeX using all of these packages and have had success recognizing the `standalone` document type. The height of my pdf now matches the height of the figure; however, the width is still quite large. Do you know if there is some different setting for the width?

Comment: I think for your case you should use the `preview` environment directly. But if you have moved your figures to a separate file, you should post a new question regarding your specific problem with a compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: @Oliver: Make sure you don't have empty lines at the begin or end of the document environment. They cause paragraphs. See [Avoid paragraph due to trailing empty line in standalone file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23279/avoid-paragraph-due-to-trailing-empty-line-in-standalone-file).

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Peter Grill. You should use `standalone` for your pictures and other more complicated figures in the future. However, for an existing document using `preview` directly is easier. However, for complicated figures which are not simply contain a single *picture environment or `\includegraphics` I would redefine the `figure` environment instead to use `preview` directly while removing the `\caption`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% remove 'demo' for real documents
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength{\PreviewBorder}{0pt}

\renewenvironment{figure}[1][]{%
    \begin{preview}%
        \renewcommand{\caption}[2][]{}%
}{%
    \end{preview}%
}

\begin{document}

text text text text text text 

\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image}%
    \caption{Some caption}
\end{figure}

text text text text text text 

\begin{figure}[b]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image}%
    \caption[short]{Some caption}
\end{figure}

text text text text text text 

\end{document}
```

This will give you one PDF which has every figure as one tight page. You then might separate it using a PDF tool like `pdftk` with the `burst` argument.