# Extraction of graphics, images via standalone mode on overleaf

Tags: graphics, floats, overleaf

I would like to extract images and TikZ diagrams as separate pdf files for each diagram on overleaf. Each output should contain only single image without extra spaces. I could not find an automated solution for this. Currently, I have prepared `minimalExport.tex` for this purpose as below. If I have modified the `documentclass` as `article`, the error is disappeared but it is not what I really need because the image is placed on a paper rather than squeezing the outer rectangle of image. How can I eliminate this error ?

I have also tried other solutions which were commented out on the below code because there was no success. Do you think this method makes sense once you would like to export each diagram as vector file (.pdf) from your latex document ?

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass{standalone}

%\usepackage{standalone}
%\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}
%\usepackage[mode=buildnew,subpreambles=true]{standalone}

\usepackage{float, graphicx}

\def\DiagramTemp{
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \resizebox{0.7\linewidth}{!}{
            \includegraphics{img/overleaf-logo.png}
        }
    \end{figure} 
}

\begin{document}
    \DiagramTemp{}
\end{document}
```

The error output on overleaf:

```
LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

 
‪jot-latex-template/minimini.tex, 22‬
There are no entries found in a list you have created. Make sure you label list entries using the \item command, and that you have not used a list inside a table.
Learn more
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.22     \DiagramTemp
                     {}
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
```

[image]

Comment: In `standalone` there is no `\linewidth` so you cannot do that. Besides, use the `\includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{}` instead of `adjustbox` which is more direct.

Comment: The above error is not related with this side @TeddyvanJerry . I have also tried the same thing without `resizebox`, and I got exactly the same output, nothing more or less. Thanks for the comment anyway.

Comment: Well, yes, just unrelated as a habit. The thing is that do not use the `figure` environment which does not make sense if your intention is to have the graph only. Just `\includegraphics` will do,

Comment: Why even use `figure` here? In the shown example the `figure` env does nothing (not even sure if it is supported by `standalone`)

Comment: @daleif and Teddy van Jerry you are both totally right. It is another scenario why I am using figure, but makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: [tables - Crop entire document around figure - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32583/crop-entire-document-around-figure) suggests `preview`. Try it out and see if it works